# How to freeze an android tablet on specific app?

Tags: android

I'm new to android development and working on a project called Arithland ATM. Arithland is a competition and I want to make a real machine similar to ATM which work with the competition score instead of money. My question is how to program android tablet to run just specific app I made and people can't close the app and go inside the android and other parts of the tablet like setting or google apps or camera or ....

I know it is possible because I saw such tablets in H&M which is a clothes shopping and they used tablets for survey.

then I put the tablet inside a physical case and it becomes something similar to ATM. note that I don't want to use a core and monitor and keyboard and other hardware to make this, I just want to make it by android tablet because of some reasons.

**EDIT:**

I found this link very helpful: [Set up Single-Purpose Devices](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html)
special thanks to [@csm_dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081206/csm-dev)

Comment: [Set up Single-Purpose Devices](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html)

Comment: @csm_dev please write it as an answer because it solved my problem.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here and I don't know enough about it to write a good full answer here. I'm glad it fixed the issue for you though :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at Screen Pinning on Security in Settings.